# Want to make my web page resolution dependent?

Tags: css, html, screen-resolution

I am creating one website in which I have created single page. The page displaying perfect in 1366 X 768 screen resolution.

But when I am opening the same page in 1024 X 768 resolution the Buttons and some text goes down.

I want to write a CSS in a way so it adjust or work properly in both the resolution. Below screen shot shows my problem.

In 1366 X 768 Resolution Page Looks Perfct! -> http://i50.tinypic.com/ac6blc.jpg

In 1024 X 768 Resolution Some elements goes down!!! -> http://i50.tinypic.com/2vxnjva.png

Can some one look my code and suggest me changes to make page display properly on both resolution.

Thanks a lot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            /*=======Global Styles==========*/
            body {
                font-family:Geordia, serif;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            a {
                color:#3E97FB;
            }
            /*==============Container=========*/
            div#container {
                position:relative;
                width:100%;
            }
            #header {
                position:absolute;
                top:5px;
                width:100%;
                background:#FFFFFF;
            }
            /*========Header 1=========*/
            #header1 {
                position:absolute;
                background:url(images/images/headerbg.png) repeat-x;
                width:100%;
                height:111px;
                left: 0px;
                top: 96px;
            }
            #header1 #form {
                float:left;
                margin-left:8%;
                margin-top:8px;
                height:70px;
                width:665px;
            }
            #form .email {
                float:left;
                margin-right:190px;
                font-family:Arial;
                font-size:12px;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#FFF;
            }
            #form .password {
                float:left;
                margin-right:2%;
                font-family:Arial;
                font-size:12px;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#FFF;
            }
            .clear {
                clear:both;
            }
            #form .input {
                float:left;
                width:200px;
                padding:7px 7px;
                margin-right:5px;
                width:200px;
                border-bottom: 1px double #171717;
                border-top: 1px double #171717;
                border-left:1px double #333333;
                border-right:1px double #333333;
            }
            #header1 .seprator {
                float:left;
                margin-left:30px;
                background:url(images/images/line.png);
                width:2px;
                height:72px;
                margin-top:15px;
            }
            #header1 .register {
                float:left;
                margin-left:6%;
                margin-top:8px;
                width:280px;
                height:70px;
            }
            .register .noac {
                color:#FFF;
                font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .loginbtn {
                float:left;
                display: inline-block;
                width:186px;
                height:40px;
            }
            .advertiserbtn {
                display: inline-block;
                margin:10px;
            }
            .publisherbtn {
                display: inline-block;
                margin:10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header-line"></div>
            <div id="header"></div>
            <!--End header-->
            <div id="header1">
                <div id="form">
                    <div class="email">Email:</div>
                    <div class="password">Password:</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="input" />
                    <input type="text" class="input" />
                    <input type="button" class="loginbtn" value="Login" />
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <!--From Div End -->
                <div class="seprator"></div>
                <div class="register">
                    <div class="noac">Don't have an account yet!</div>
                    <input type="button" class="advertiserbtn"
                    value="Free Register" />
                    <input type="button" class="publisherbtn" value="Premium Registration"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End header1-->
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
        <!--End footer-->
        </div>
        <!--End Content Div-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Search google for responsive web design

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS media queries to alter the size of elements as the screen resolution increases. This can be done multiple times to even allow your elements to re size and reorder for mobile/tablet/laptop/desktop screen resolutions. Here is an example:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
   .loginbtn {
                float: left;
                display: inline;
                width: 156px;
                height: 40px;
            }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1366px) {
   .loginbtn {
                width: 186px;
            }
}
```

Go for a mobile first approach an declare your styles for the smallest width first. Change your widths at your breakpoints.

Comment: this works with buttons for which we are using image as background?

Comment: The above media queries are just an example, you can use them with all elements on a page i.e. divs and tables. If you need and image to fill a div you can set the % size of the div and use ' background-image: contain' to keep the image inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is that the page doesn't get smaller than a specific value.
The easiest way to achieve this is to give you entire page a `min-width`. A horizontal scroll bar will appear if the window gets to small then.

Comment: for which class I need to define min-width? body??

Comment: @user210111 the body or your #content div

Answer (score -3):

You should try specifying the dimensions as percentage, instead of all px.